# Problems with probability proof

Tags: probability

I am stuck. The problem is if A and B are independent events prove that A' and B' are also independent. I got P(A union B) must be 1/2. I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are probably wrong.  What is your definition of independence?  What is $\Pr(A')$?

Comment: My definition is P(A')=1-P(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A$ and $B$ are independent.  Then 
$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$, or equivalently, $P(B) = P(B|A)$, $P(A) = P(A|B)$.

Playing off of the hint given in Ross Millikan's answer, here is another approach using conditional probability.

$$P(B'|A) = \frac{P(B'\cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A \setminus (B\cap A))}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A) - P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A) - P(B)P(A)}{P(A)}$$ $$ = 1 - P(B) = P(B')$$

This shows that $P(B'|A) = P(B')$, and hence $B'$ and $A$ are independent.  We want to show that $P(B'|A') = P(B')$.
$$P(B'|A') = \frac{P(B'\cap A')}{P(A')} =\frac{P(B'\setminus(B'\cap A))}{P(A')} =  \frac{P(B') - P(B'\cap A)}{1 - P(A)}$$
and since we previously proved that $B'$ and $A$ are independent,
$$= \frac{P(B') - P(B')P(A)}{1 - P(A)} = \frac{P(B')(1-P(A))}{1-P(A)} = P(B')$$

Hence we have proven that $A'$ and $B'$ are independent.

Comment: Which assumes that $P(A)\ne0$ and $P(A)\ne1$. Since this hypothesis is unnecessary, this is a good indication that conditional probabilities should be avoided here. For a proof with no division, see @David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since, by Demorgan's law,  $ A'\cap B' =(A\cup B)'$

$$\eqalign{
P(A'\cap B')&= 1-P(A\cup B )\cr
&=1-\bigl[ P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)\bigr]\cr
&=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(AB)\cr
&=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A)P(B)\cr
&=P(A')-P(B)\bigl(1-P(A)\bigr)\cr
&=P(A')-P(B)P(A')\cr
&=P(A')\bigl(1-P(B)\bigr)\cr
&=P(A')P(B'). 
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have no data to say what $P(A\cup B)$ is.  $A$ could be rolling a $1$ on a red die and $B$ rolling a $1$ on a green die.  Certainly $P(A\cup B)\neq \frac 12$

Independent just means that the occurrence of $A$ doesn't change the chance of $B$, so $P(B)=P(B|A)=P(B|A')$  You want to show that  $P(B')=P(B'|A')$.  It might help to make a Venn diagram and label the probabilities of each region.